# Teradata to Hive equivalent

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, teradata

I am trying to convert a Teradata Query to Hive Query.

Partly converted query is:

```
CREATE TABLE x.calendar_day_tmp AS SELECT k.*,s.gregorian_date
FROM x.multisave_store_level AS k
INNER JOIN x.calendar_day AS s
ON gregorian_date BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
AND (SELECT MAX(wk) FROM x.climate_data) = s.wk;
```

I know that non-equi joins are not supported in Hive.

`start_date` and `end_date` are in `multisave_store_level` but not in `calendar_day`.

`gregorian_date` is in `calendar_day` but not in `multisave_store_level`

Is there an efficient solution to the above query?

Comment: Non-equi joins have to be moved into your where clause.  May not be efficient, but it's the only way I'm aware of.